# How can I set up a GCP Cloud SQL instance to trust an Active Directory Domain for Windows authentication?

Tags: sql-server, windows, google-cloud-platform, active-directory, google-cloud-sql

I am currently porting a Desktop application to Google Cloud SQL and need to allow users to login using Windows Active Directory authentication. I cannot seem to join the SQL instance to the domain because SQL instances dont allow system access. Im not sure of any other way to let a sql instance trust a domain.

In short- How can I set up a GCP Cloud SQL instance to trust an Active Directory Domain without system access to the SQL instance?

Answer (score 2):

Google Cloud SQL for SQL Server does not support domain joins to your Active Directory instance.

At this time, instance-level database access is via SQL Server Authentication (username, password).

Answer (score 1):

Google Cloud SQL for SQL Server now supports Active Directory Authentication as a preview feature. Here's the announcement blog post: [Cloud SQL for SQL Server—now with Active Directory authentication](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/databases/windows-authentication-now-supported-by-googles-cloud-sql-database)

A walkthrough of setting up a GCP Cloud SQL instance to trust an Active Directory Domain is covered in this blog post:

[Create a SQL Server instance integrated with Active Directory using Google Cloud SQL](https://jsimonweb.medium.com/create-a-sql-server-instance-integrated-with-active-directory-using-google-cloud-sql-597911c49ec7)